# Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\text{Arcsin}(n^{-2}z)$ converges normally in the whole complex plane and that the function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

**Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\text{Arcsin}(n^{-2}z)$ converges normally in the whole complex plane and that the function $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ defined by the rule of correspondence $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\text{Arcsin}(n^{-2}z)$ is analytic in the domain $D=\mathbb{C}\sim \{z: \text{Im}(z)=0 \text{ and }|z|\geq 1\}$. Deduce from this that $g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n^4-z^2)^{-1/2}$ also defines a funcion that is analytic in $D$.**

I have been thinking about this exercise and I know that to show that this series normally converges on $\mathbb{C}$ it is sufficient to show that it converges uniformly in every closed disc contained in $\mathbb{C}$. Let us then take $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ and $r>0$ such that $\bar{\Delta}:=D[z_0,r]\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ and $z\in \bar{\Delta}$ and let us see that $\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\text{Arcsin}(n^{-2}z)\right\}_n$ converges uniformly in $\bar{\Delta}$ ... I do not know what else I can do, could someone help me please? How can I prove that $\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\text{Arcsin}(n^{-2}z)\right\}_n$ converges uniformly on $\bar{\Delta}$? Where $f_n(z)=\text{Arcsin}(n^{-2}z)$ is analytical? If I know where $f_n$ is analytic, I could say that $f$ is analytic in this region because the convergence is normal and could apply the Weierstrass theorem. How can I do the second part with $g$?, thank you very much.

Comment: You could see how $ Arcsin(X) $ relates to $ X $, maybe using Jordan's Inequality for $ Sin(X) $; draw the graph to see. Then use the Weierstrass M test.  What about the derivative of $ Arcsin $?

Comment: @kieran Why can Jordan's inequality help me relate $\text{Arcsin}(x)$ to $x$? What is $x$? $x=\frac{z}{n^2}$?

Comment: For $ X $ real, $ -1 \le x \le 1 $  $ Arcsin $ is increasing. $ \lvert Arcsin(X) \rvert \le \lvert \frac {\pi X} {2} {\rvert } $ . Replace $ X $ by $ \frac {X} {n^{2}} $ to get absolute value of each term $ \le \frac {\pi} {2 n^{2}} $. So, uniform conv by Weierstrass for $ X $ real. [-1 , 1] is a set with limit points. So, can extend function by analytic continuation, taking account of where $ Arcsin(Z) $ is defined. Derivative of function and series is analytic by Cauchy.